# Unable to install r-lidr on MacOS with conda

Tags: conda, rlidar

I am unable to get https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-lidr installed on MacOS Monterey 12.2.1 with conda 4.11.0.

This is my environment.yml:

```
name: r-lidr-test
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - r-base
  - r-lidr
```

`conda env create` results in:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package r-base conflicts for:
r-lidr -> r-base[version='3.4.1.*|>=3.4.1,<3.4.2.0a0']
r-lidr -> r-data.table -> r-base[version='3.3.2.*|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=4.0,<4.1.0a0|>=4.1,<4.2.0a0|>=3.5.1,<3.5.2.0a0']
r-base
```

If I try with mamba version 0.15.3,  `mamba env create` results in this:

```
Looking for: ['r-base', 'r-lidr']

Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides compiler-rt 4.0.1 hcfea43d_1 needed by clang-4.0.1-1
```

Can you provide any help (including hacks/workarounds)?